# Not seeing all fields in Rename Tabs and Labels

Tags: field-service-lightning, label, standard-field, fieldservice

We are working on **FSL**.

We need to rename the field label for **Location** to something else in **Work Order**.

I went to *Rename Tabs and Labels* in **Setup** but not able to see **Location** in the field list to rename label:

[image]

There are some more fields that are not present in *Rename Tabs and Labels* page.

I also tried using Override:

[image]

But not able to see the **Location** field.

What am I missing here?

Comment: did you tried from override in setup

Comment: Have you tried other Label as in the screenshot it's only showing standard field in Rename tab and label and Custom field in Override. Where is this location field I mean on which object and if standard or custom field.

Comment: Location is a standard field. I checked the whole page of **Rename Tabs and Labels** but the Location was nowhere. This field is on Work Order object.

Comment: did you tried renaming location object from "Rename Tabs and Labels page" when you press next on that page you get all the fields for it, try renaming location field label from there.

Comment: Not able to see any "Next" button or link there.

Comment: Rename Tabs and Labels ->Select Location->next for getting its fields and renaming location field label from there

Comment: I need to rename the field label in work order

Comment: so location is a lookup right?

Comment: Yes. Location is a lookup in Work Order.

Comment: so i don't think there is any possible way to change label of lookup field from the workorder you will have to go in the lookup object and change label from there it will then change the label on work order but This would also change the label for location all the Lookup fields.